# ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sectionName") throws ConfigurationErrorsException for custom section

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have made a custom section in my app.config file but I can't manage to retrieve it. I always get a ConfigurationErrorsException.

```
public class UdpSettings : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static UdpSettings settings
      = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("UdpSettings") as UdpSettings;

    public static UdpSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return settings;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("puerto"
      , DefaultValue = 20
      , IsRequired = false)]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = 1
      , MaxValue = 65535)]
    public int Puerto
    {
        get { return (int)this["puerto"]; }
        set { this["puerto"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("puertoTaconet"
      , DefaultValue = 20
      , IsRequired = false)]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = 1
      , MaxValue = 65535)]
    public int PuertoTaconet
    {
        get { return (int)this["puertoTaconet"]; }
        set { this["puertoTaconet"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("rutaArchivoGeocerca"
     , IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "  ~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;’\"|"
      , MinLength = 1
      , MaxLength = 256)]
    public string RutaArchivoGeocerca
    {
        get { return (string)this["rutaArchivoGeocerca"]; }
        set { this["rutaArchivoGeocerca"] = value; }
    }


    [ConfigurationProperty("rutaArchivoConfig"
     , IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "  ~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;’\"|"
      , MinLength = 1
      , MaxLength = 256)]
    public string RutaArchivoConfig
    {
        get { return (string)this["rutaArchivoConfig"]; }
        set { this["rutaArchivoConfig"] = value; }
    }


    [ConfigurationProperty("rutaModem2"
     , IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "  ~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;’\"|"
      , MinLength = 1
      , MaxLength = 256)]
    public string RutaModem2
    {
        get { return (string)this["rutaModem2"]; }
        set { this["rutaModem2"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("rutaModem1"
     , IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "  ~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;’\"|"
      , MinLength = 1
      , MaxLength = 256)]
    public string RutaModem1
    {
        get { return (string)this["rutaModem1"]; }
        set { this["rutaModem1"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("rutaFirmwareEquipo"
      , IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "  ~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;’\"|"
      , MinLength = 1
      , MaxLength = 256)]
    public string RutaFirmwareEquipo
    {
        get { return (string)this["rutaFirmwareEquipo"]; }
        set { this["rutaFirmwareEquipo"] = value; }
    }
}
```

And this is my app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="UdpSettings" type="UDP_Taco.Modelo.UdpSettings" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </configSections>
  <UdpSettings
    puerto ="1001"
    rutaArchivoGeocerca ="C:\Test"
    rutaArchivoConfig ="C:\Test"
    rutaModem2 ="C:\Test"
    rutaModem1 ="C:\Test"
    rutaFirmwareEquipo="C:\Test"
    puertoTaconet ="1015"/>
</configuration>
```

I'm feel there's something wrong in the "type" attribute of my section. What should go in there?

"ConfigurationManager.GetSection("UdpSettings")" is the line that throws ConfigurationErrorsException.

Comment: Try to specify full assebly-qualified type name is a Type attribute of section element. If this does not help could you please add full error message?

Comment: thanks, "UDP_Taco.Modelo.UdpSettings, UDP-Taxi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a full assembly-qualified type name int a `type` attribute of a `section` element. Like this:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="UdpSettings" type="UDP_Taco.Modelo.UdpSettings, UDP-Taxi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
</configSections>
```